# PHP mbstring doesn't work, but I set everything

Tags: php, mbstring

I set in the php.ini file the mbstring, php_mbstring.dll is on its place, but php can't load the mudule. I tried everything, what I found on stackoverflow, or anywhere else, but nothing.
-php directory is located in C:\php
-php_mbstring.dll is located in C:\php\ext\php_mbstring.dll
-;extension_dir = "ext" row is outcommented, but I tried remove the semicolon, and set it to "C:\php\ext", also tried it with / signs
-extension=mbstring row has no semicolon before tried to name it to php_mbstring.dll, tried to give the whole path (C:\php\ext\php_mbstring.dll), tried it with outcommented extension_dir = "ext", tried it all the possible ways, with \ sign and / sign, but always the same failure...
-another device of mine (notebook) runs the mbstring, I copied the dll file from it, tried with that all the possibilities above, tried to download another dll file, also tortured through the ways above, but nothing. The dll file is on its place, the path is authentical, it's enabled in the php.ini, but it doesn't work...

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring'
> (tried: C:\php\ext\mbstring (A megadott modul nem tal├ílhat├│.),
> C:\php\ext\php_mbstring.dll (A megadott modul nem tal├ílhat├│.)) in
> Unknown on line 0

Using Atom editor and Atom live server, it outputs the following:

> Listening on http://localhost:8000 Document root is
> C:\Users\ferenczi\Desktop\Saját cuccok\html
> programozás\Projectek\Hander at line 0, file Unknown[Mon May 17
> 05:40:46 2021] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
> library 'mbstring' (tried: C:\php\ext\mbstring (A megadott modul nem
> talC!lhatC3.), C:\php\ext\php_mbstring.dll (A megadott modul nem
> talC!lhatC3.)) [Mon May 17 05:40:56 2021] PHP 7.4.12 Development
> Server (http://localhost:8000) started

Everything else working perfect. PHP working, SQL queries working, mysql extension working.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to install php-mbstring package and let it enable the mbstring extension automatically:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

if you want to enable or diable, please go with the below command

```
sudo phpdismod mbstring # disable mbstring extension
sudo phpenmod mbstring # enable mbstring extension
```

Try this!

Comment: I'm a beginner yet, I don't know, where to write this. I looked for where to write these commands, but read everywhere, it's for Linux... I have Windows... and I tried write it to cmd.exe, and also tried php.exe, but either of these hasn't work.

Comment: Nayana, your answer is relevant for Linux only, while the question is certainly for Windows.